# Plotting list of picturelists in several plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'v got a list with picture-path's and i want to "plot" them in several plots e.g:

```
list = [['./path1/pic1.jpg','./path1/pic2.jpg',...],['./path2/pic1.jpg',...],[...]]
```

the output has to be in this e.g 3 plots with the pictures from the list's

i've tried that way but it seems to be not right because i get this Error

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(list))
    for image in list:
        im = Image.open(image)
        ax.imshow(im)


AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imshow'
```

I also tried `im = mpimg.imread(image)` which gaves me the same result and `ax.imshow(image)` without any "opening"

maybe someone know how do do this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subplots` function returns a `ndarray` of axes. It's length will be the same as the number of subplots you created. So you have to index it and show the image on the right one.

```
images = [...]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(images))
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    im = Image.open(image)
    axes[i].imshow(im)
```

Comment: well by doing this i get the Error `TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing
`

Comment: @Linda the exact same code from my answer, or you changed something? If you changed something post the changed version, and if it's the exact same code, what version of mpl are you using?

Comment: Perhaps add `squeeze=False` to the subplots command for the case where the length of the list equals 1. With `squeeze=True` that case would return the axes instead of the array containing the axes.

Comment: @Linda Also if you use `squeeze=False` change the last line to `axes[0][i].imshow(im)` since then the axes will be a 2D array.

Comment: After Updating my mpl Viktor's answers works very well ! Thank you

Comment: as a side note, I would suggest using `for ax, image in zip(axes.flat, images):` for the loop. (or `itertools.izip` if you want to be fancy).